# ASIHttpRequest resume Downloading

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, asihttprequest, resume-download

I've got question that similiar to this post [ASIHTTP asynchrounous pdf download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445106/asihttp-asynchrounous-pdf-download)

I am going to resume download using setTemporaryFileDownloadPath: but the weird thing is when I called setDelegate to self and start the connection asynchronously, the cache won't save it to temporaryFileDownloadPath but instead I remark the set delegate, the cache will save to the path.

```
    _conn = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:_currentURL];
    [_conn setDownloadDestinationPath:_currentFileNameWithPath]; 
    [_conn setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:tempPdfLocation];     
    [_conn setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
    //[_conn setDelegate:self];
    [_conn startAsynchronous];
```

I've found that whenever - (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data: was called the cache won't saved. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the same thing. Only difference is that I had to set the following selectors:

```
[_conn setDidFailSelector:@selector(downloadDidFail:)];
[_conn setDidFinishSelector:@selector(downloadDidFinish:)];
[_conn setDidStartSelector:@selector(downloadDidStart:)];
```

And not implement any of the other delegate methods specified as optional in the `ASIHTTPRequestDelegate` protocol. Now the download works perfectly and will call the set selectors when needed.

Comment: But I need to track the download progress by byte so I need the [data length] from delegate request didReceiveData:.

Comment: If you know the total size (which you are able to), you can attach a custom progress delegate to receive progress and calculate that to bytes downloaded.

Comment: yes, it worked. I used the custom progress delegate. Thanks a lot!